# How to get all the functions and there files on which a PHP function depend

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically I would like to use several WordPress functions anytime between the WordPress is loading. So I need to make sure that the function I am calling exists and so do all other functions on which it depends.

I already have a way to add checkpoints for that, but I need to know for sure first that after this point all the dependencies of this function are loaded, so for this I need the list of files and functions on which a function depends.

For example:
If I need to use `sanitize_user()` of the WordPress, it internally uses multiple functions of WordPress, which internally calls multiple functions like:
`sanitize_user()` -> `wp_strip_all_tags()` -> `__()` -> `translate()` and so on..

So is there a way through which I can get all the required functions and in which files they are present?

Recently I was using the `current_user_can()` function, just by checking if it exists and my site got a critical error, as it internally depends upon pluggable.php which is loaded after all the plugins are loaded.

References:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

Comment: A good IDE could help you with locating the functions in the codebase. Or use `grep`. But if they're all built-in wordpress functions, surely they should be included in every script without you needing to worry about it? Are you saying you need to call these functions potentially _before_ Wordpress includes them? Why would you need/want to do  that?

Comment: Yes, it can happen that, I might be calling a function before WordPress includes all its dependencies. I have a use case, and the tool I am building depends on this.

Comment: What is the use case? In programming generally, and in php, including all the code references the program needs is always the first step you take before doing anything else, so that you can sure you've got everything you need. What is it about this task which means it cannot be done after all the inclusions have finished? I can't imagine this is something wordpress would suggest or recommend that you do when integrating your code

Comment: Also what are you actually going to do if the functions aren't there? Include them yourself? In that case, again, why not wait for wordpress to do it, in a properly managed way? I am starting to wonder if I can smell an XY problem

Comment: I understand why you can sense issues here. I won't be able to share the use case. But in case, the dependencies are not loaded yet, I will skip. The dependencies will be present 99% of the time, I am just trying to make sure in those edge case site don't throw critical errors.

Comment: For a use case example: 
See the below condition.

Suppose I have attached to a hook in wp-config.php itself, which gets triggered by multiple files of core WordPress. Now in this function of mine I am using some of the WordPress functions to do some things, I would want to make sure that they are only used if all the dependencies are loaded properly.

This is just an example so that I am able to convey how one can utilise it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255365/discussion-between-harshm-and-adyson).